# BottomSheetDialogFragment sets wrong background color for Dark theme

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-theme

I have recently added BottomSheetDialogFragment to my app, but it shows background color for Material Dark theme as white. Even when I use

```
android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
```

for the root layout of the dialog, it is still white (but this attr is ok outside of the dialog). Has anyone ever had this problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The appearance of a bottom sheet dialog is controlled by an attribute named `bottomSheetDialogTheme`, which [defaults to](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog.java#L209) `Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog`. To achieve a dark background (and also white text, properly colored controls, etc.), you need to override it in your activity theme:

```
<style name="YourActivityTheme" parent="...">
    <!-- ... -->

    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped me with my problem.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted! Also set <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog</item> in light theme for consistency

Answer (score 2):

I just hit this problem. I used attribute you mentioned in the root layout of the dialog and it helped me.

```
android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
```

Comment: Still the same for me. I solved this problem with my custom color attribute